# AngularJS reloaded controller dont change DOM

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, controller

I have an angularJs Application.

In there i have a "LayoutCtrl" (LayoutController) which is saying (for example) "How many head menu links are existing".

I have created my Controller and my Service - it works fine.
Now, in some cases the site needs new HeadMenu-Links (e.g. at login / logout) or widgets (little boxes with extra content at side).

So i getted the $scope from the LayoutCtrl to the controller (for grabbing it later and chaning its values).

At testing (alert some values) my $scope has always the corrent values, also changes in the returned JSON (from php service).

But the DOM dont changes.

What could it be?

The part of Layout:

```
<div ng-controller="LayoutCtrl">
    <div desc='header' class='header' >
        <a desc='hp_link' class='hp_link'  href="#{{header.index}}">
            <img desc='banner' class='banner'  ng-src="{{header.banner}}" src="zkLib/f/img/ajax-loader-sm.gif">
        </a>
        <div desc='headerRow' class='headerRow'>
            <div desc='headerMenu' class='headerMenu'>
                <span ng-repeat="m in header.mHead">
                    <span desc='hmLink' class='hmLink' >
                        <a desc='headerLink' class='headerLink'  href="{{m.link}}">{{m.text}}
                            <img desc='headerImg' class='headerImg'  ng-src="ico/{{m.image}}" heightt="16px;"/>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div desc='networksMenu' class='networksMenu'>
                <span ng-repeat="n in header.network">
                    <span desc='nwLink' class='nwLink' >
                        <a desc='networkLinK' class='networkLinK'  target="_blank" title="{{n.name}}" href="{{n.link}}">
                            <img desc='networkImg' class='networkImg'  ng-src="zkLib/f/img/icons/{{n.icon}}"/>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
app.controller("LayoutCtrl", ["$scope", "$route",
"HeaderService", "AppService", "WidgetsService", "FooterService",
function($scope, $route, HeaderService, AppService, WidgetsService, FooterService) {
    $scope.refresh = function(route) {  
        HeaderService.query().then(
            function(result) { $scope.header = result.data }, function(result) {}
        );
        WidgetsService.query().then(
            function(result) { $scope.widgets = result.data }, function(result) {}
        )
        $scope.$route = route;
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.header));
    };

    $scope.refresh($route);

    AppService.query().then(
        function(result) { $scope.app = result.data }, function(result) {}
    );
    FooterService.query().then(
        function(result) { $scope.footer = result.data }, function(result) {}
    );
    AppService.$scope = $scope;
}]);
```

One of the called services:

```
app.factory('HeaderService', ['$http', '$q',
function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

    service.query = function() {
        var data = $http.get(sAddr('header'));
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        deffered.resolve(data);
        return deffered.promise;
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

(sAddr returns the corrent server path to service)

On other Controllers (e.g. index page, user page...) i call

```
AppService.$scope.refresh($route);
```

to force the controller refresh (new Menus? New Widgets?) and it reload correctly (i think) - the alert in the code above print me out the correct json.

But the DOM dont change.
What i´m doing wrong?

I´ve builded this pattern with this example code from an other StackOverFlow-Question:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/694/)

I´ve build an similar example with the Servoce.$scope.refresh-Call on other Controller (TestController) - it worked fine... but here - with no differences, not.

Thanks for answers - Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try $scope.$apply() or $rootScope.$digest() to get all of the data refreshed in your DOM. Updating any of the models from outside of the controller it is bound to will update the data but Angular doesn't know about it. Sometimes, setting a watch with $scope.$watch and updating the values inside the controller will give you the refreshed data in the DOM.

Trying a $scope.$digest() at the end of your promises is also an option.

http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/

Comment: I´ve try it, but maybe i dont really understand the concept of it... :/

I´ve looked your link and the Error page while getting "alredy apply"-Error, but nothing helps...
My Controllers hasve no directives, so where i have to apply and when? (And the Services dont know the AppService with scope in it normally)